# How do i let user create a subfolder and upload files there in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I basically want to let user create their own repository or a sub-folder in their media/user_id/ folder and upload files in the folder they have created.

Answer (score 5):

You can allow users to create a folder structure in their profiles quite easily-  a folder structure conceptually is just a set of pointers, it can easily be achieved using django models, to my mind that would be a much nicer way of doing it rather than letting users create actual folders on the server, which could be annoying to maintain.

You just need your image model to have an optional `folder` fk , and your `folder` model can have a fk reference to itself. This gives you a lot more control over folders and allows you to easily provide the user with options to move files from folder to folder, delete folders and all contained images, etc.

As a basic example:

```
class UserFolder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Folder", null=True,)  # self-referential

class UserImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    # Optional, null folder could just mean it resides in the base user folder
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, null=True,)
```

Comment: I am new to django can you explain a bit more clearly, please.

Comment: Without writing the code for you, Pete's answer is pretty clear. If you're new to Django development concepts, perhaps you should start with the official tutorial. It covers pretty much everything you need to answer your question. +1 from me Pete